# Using ICU's UChar as a replacement for wchar?

Tags: c++, unicode, icu, wchar

Since I heard there are many problems with the `wchar_t` type (compiler-specific width), I was very interested by the [International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/) project.

But, ICU seems a bit heavier for my needs. 
I only need something that could provide an alternative to `wchar_t` as well as the string-related functions like `wcscpy`,`wcslen` and so on.

Comment: As you already pointed out, `wchar_t` has very different behaviour on different compilers. *Which* behaviour do you need?

Comment: If width is the only issue, why not use `char32_t` ? And TBH `wcslen` is a bad idea in C++, use `std::wstring::size`

Comment: What "problems" are you having with `wchar_t`? There's a lot of hand-waving and FUD, not a lot of real world issues.

Comment: `std::wstring` uses `wchar_t` (hense its name). Use `std::basic_string<char16_t>` or `std::basic_string<uint16_t>`, or even `std::u16string` if available in your compiler.

Comment: What specific issue(s) are you having and what are you trying to solve? UChar is simply a typedef of wchar_t on many platforms. ICU is very nice and can certainly be slimmed down for specific functionality, but we need to know what you're really after.